# Finding Normal Modes in MATLAB of system of equations

Tags: matlab, simulation, physics, symbolic-math, differential-equations

I'm wondering how to go from a system of differential equations to finding normal modes using Matlab.

Say I have a system `[A]ddx` = `[b]` (using equationsToMatrix), where `[A]` is n by n, b is n by 1, and `ddx` is n by 1, a vector of the 2nd derivatives of my generalized coordinates. `[A]` and `[b]` are functions of `x`.

To find normal modes, I want `[M]ddx` + `[K]x` = 0.

I'm not sure how to go from `[A]` and `[b]` to `[M]` and `[K]`, it may be really simple and I'm missing it.

I would like to find these matrices and be able to calculate normal modes values of `x` to use as initial conditions.

Comment: I'm trying to linearize this about an equilibrium so I'm assuming that any first derivative of x is 0.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not read carefully, you wrote that A and b are dependent on x. What is preventing you from computing the first degree Taylor polynomial of A^{-1}b? Actually, you can set `M=A(x*), K=-b'(x*)`, where `x*` is the stationary point.

Comment: But `b` is n by 1, shouldn't `K` be n by n?

Comment: The Jacobian of a vector valued function of a vector of arguments is a matrix. If it helps, write `Db(x*)` or `J_b(x*)` or something with the partial symbol instead of the simple looking `b'(x*)`.

Comment: Let's step back a second; I'm using Lagrange's equations to get `A` and `b` by using MATLAB's jacobian function. Is there a way I can go from Lagrange's equations to `M` and `K` to get the normal modes?

Comment: As you have no first derivative, one might assume that the Lagrangian is separable? L = x'^TMx'/2 - V(x)? Then M is M and K is the Hessian of V in the equilibrium point.

Comment: And then I can take eig(M-K)? I'm confused as to how I use these matrices to get normal modes and find initial conditions to exhibit these modes (I'm working with a multi-link pendulum)

Comment: The equation to solve is $(M-q*K)*v=0$, that is, the characteristic equation is $det(M-q*K)=0$. There should be library routines for this generalized eigenvalue problem. But as `M` is regular, you can also use `eig(M^-1*K)`.